# Bluez DBus: client server implementation

Tags: python, server, dbus, bluez, gatt

I need help to setup my project. In particular, my project is a C/C++ project.

This project involves different components that must communicate exploiting Bluetooth Low Energy.

**Components:**
The components can be classified into two different categories: a *mobile component* (such as a tablet android or an Ipad) and a *raspberry component* (a Raspberry Pi W board with a BLE adapter). In the system, there can be 1 mobile component and from 1 to N raspberry components

**Desired Behavior:**
According to the project requirements, the Raspberry components should notify their presence in order to be detected from the tablet. The tablet has to scan for nearby raspberry and eventually connect to one of the scanned devices. Once the connection is established the tablet has to send at least two strings to the raspberry.

I downloaded the last version of Bluez and I saw the python scripts in the *test* folder: ***example-gatt-server*** and ***example-advertising***. Unfortunately, I have no experience with python. So I looked for an equivalent C code but didn't find anything.

1. Can anyone help me to find a GATT server in C able to advertise and receive connection request?
2. Is it correct for my requirements to implement the code for the Raspberry as the one in the gatt-server-example?

Thanks

[EDIT]:

My boss agrees with me to use these python scripts instead of using some C/C++ equivalent. As said before I have no experience using python, so I need some help.

1. Which types of data are accepted from the gatt-server? Can I pass a string to it?
2. If I want to modify two of the implemented services (the ones identified using UUID 12345678-....) to pass a string can I do this?
3. In the gatt-server example, there is a service that seems to deal with the encryption mechanism. If I try to send the string "goofy" is this encrypted, sent and decrypted once received by the gatt-server?

Thanks

Comment: Is it a requirement to use C/C++? Or can you use bash scripts instead?

Comment: Hi @YoussifSaeed, it could be not mandatory ... I will check with the chef of the project. I'm looking for an equivalent C/C++ code because of my background. Anyway, I'm testing these two examples and it seems to do what I 'm looking for. Maybe I will spend some time in order to adapt them to my requirements. Could you tell me if it is possible to merge the two examples in one?

Comment: Hi, again @YoussifSaeed. I edited the main question with new information. Please take a look to it